# base64 image is not showing in email template

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add application logo in the email template format but image is not visible. I just inspected the image from the email then I found that src in the img tag is not showing why?

```
<img data-imagetype="DataUri" blockedimagesrc="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

Base64 data image is not assigned to the **blockedimagesrc** attribute rather than the **src** attribute as mention above.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try using the Content ID (`cid:`) scheme - see [How do i attach image in email...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63625403/12567365). That may not work if your mail server is replacing your `src` attribute with its `blockedimagesrc` attribute.

Comment: You can also add a [mre] to the question and research other related questions such as [How to stop HTML email <img> src attribute from being removed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34474120/12567365), and [Image not displayed in Outlook in ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49379598/12567365) (are you using Outlook?) - and probably others.

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames, I was using outlook and found out while searching that outlook no longer supports base64 image. So I have made it workable by keeping the public image url for now.